# Mysql server failing to start

Tags: mysql

I'm newbie in MySQL and I have installed MySQL5.5 Server and Client in my Debian Wheezy. All I did was enter "aptitude install myqsl-server". Now, I have no idea what to do to create my first table of data, I tried to enter with the following command as root(have no idea why I have to do this as root):

```
/etc/init.d/mysql start
```

The output was:

> [FAIL] Starting MySQL database server: mysqld . . . . . . . . . . . .
>   . . failed!

I tried to see what is in the system log in `/var/log/` and there is nothing there!

First, I tried to access `/var/log/mysql`, and this folder is empty, then I tried to read it `vim /var/log/mysql.err` and `/var/log/mysql.log`, both are empty too!

So, what is wrong? What is the next steps to create my first table of data?

Comment: This is a server related question, ask it at [Unix & Linux stack exchange community](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or even at http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 2):

Check the ownership on the /var/log/mysql and /var/mysqld directories.

```
ls -ld /var/log/mysql
ls -ld /var/mysqld
```

According to [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=801607) you may have to change ownership to mysql:

```
chown mysql:mysql /var/log/mysql
chown mysql:mysql /var/mysqld
```

Comment: `drwxr-s--- 2 mysql adm 4096 Jun 27 16:12 /var/log/mysql`<br/>

`ls: cannot access /var/mysqld: No such file or directory`<br/>

`chown: changing ownership of `/var/log/mysql': Operation not permitted`<br/>

`chown: cannot access `/var/mysqld': No such file or directory`<br/>

Comment: "you may have to change ownership to mysql:" But how can i do that? With chmod 777?

Comment: It looks like the directories don't exist. It may be worth your while to create them: `mkdir /var/log/mysql` and `mkdir /var/mysqld`. Make sure you use `chown` to change ownership to mysql. See my answer above on how to do that.

Comment: I created the /var/mysqld folder and changed the ownership with "chgrp mysql /var/log/mysql" and "chgrp mysql /var/mysqld". Absolutely nothing changed! And doing as you said, with "chown mysql:mysql /var/log/mysql" has the same result.

Comment: Be sure to `chown` the /var/mysqld folder as well.

Comment: Yes i did. After that i tried "/etc/init.d/mysql start" and failed to start and that folder, "/var/log/mysql" is empty and the files "/var/log/mysql.err" and "/var/log/mysql.log" both empty too.

Comment: All righty, try checking out [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/starting-server.html). The comments at the bottom may be helpful. Be sure to check the process list to see if there are any processes you need to kill. If that all fails, you may want to reinstall the package.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Elena. I'll have to reinstall the package. Accidentally i clicked in downvote for you, after that i tried to click in upvote. I hope i have not harmed you.